# I/O error on GET "Connection refused" during unit test of custom Spring endpoint that hits a default swagger endpoint in a Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test, mockmvc

I have an endpoint that comes from a gradle dependency, lets say its `/v3/doc`

I needed to expose an endpoint, lets call it, `/v1/info` that hits /v3/doc internally, massages, some of the data that comes out, then returns that piece of data to whomever called /v1/info

I wrote the code for it (below i am omitting the massaging part for simplicity), but the unit tests throw the error described during test execution.

My endpoint looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("v1/info")
    public @ResponseBody SomePojo swag(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String s = retrieve(request
                                .getRequestURL()
                                .toString()
                                .split("v1")[0] // get the base URL and tack on what i need
                                .concat("v3/doc")
                        );

        return new Gson().fromJson(s, SomePojo.class)
    }

    private String retrieve(String url) {
        return new RestTemplate()
            .getForEntity(url, String.class)
            .getBody();
    }
}
```

unit test looks like:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "local")
public class MyControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void testEndpoint() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/info")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .characterEncoding("utf-8"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
}
```

error looks like:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost/v3/doc": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

im wondering if it has something to do with the port?? because when i run the app on 8001 i can hit `/v3/doc` and `/v1/info` no problem. But as you can see when the unit tests run, there is no port, just localhost. I didnt think that mattered though. Will i have to create some kind of fake mvc stub?

Answer (score 0):

You could try not autowiring the MockMvc and instead instantiate it in the setup like:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Before
public void setUp() {
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test context created only around `@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)`. Thats means no another endpoints as well as applications server also did not running in this case. And when you call restTemplate it fails.

In case of you wanna test you should move RestTemplate creation outside method and made `@Autowirible` for example. After you can easily mock it in your test.

Or in case of your third party service is always available you got error because the port is not defined, but it is look conceptually incorrect for unit test.